# Inserting data to file in c

Tags: c, file, pointers, fseek

I need to add a string before the 45<sup>th</sup> byte in an existing file. I tried using `fseek` as shown below.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char str[] = "test";     

    fp = fopen(FILEPATH,"a");
    fseek(fp,-45, SEEK_END);                
    fprintf(fp,"%s",str);
    fclose(fp);     
    return(0);
}
```

I expected that this code will add "test" before the 45<sup>th</sup> char from EOF, instead, it just appends "test" to the EOF.

Please help me to find the solution.

This is continuation of my previous question
[Append item to a file before last line in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262886/append-item-to-a-file-before-last-line-in-c)

Comment: which previous question? Could you please link to it?

Comment: Thanks alexandre and Brian. I got the solution below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open it with mode r+ (if it already exists) or a+ (if it doesn't exist and you want to create it).  Since you're seeking to 45 bytes before the end of file, I'm assuming it already exists.

```
fp = fopen(FILEPATH,"r+");
```

The rest of your code is fine.  Also note that this will not *insert* the text, but will overwrite whatever is currently at that position in the file.

ie, if your file looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Then after running this code, it will look like this:

```
xxxxxxxtestxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

If you really want to insert and not overwrite, then you need to read all the text from SEEK_END-45 to EOF into memory, write *test* and then write the text back

Answer (score 3):

Don't open it as  append (`a`) if you plan to write at arbitrary positions; it will force all writes to the end of the file.  You can use `r+` to read or write anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid platform-specific configurations, always explicitely indicate the binary or text mode in your fopen() call.

This will save you hours of desperations if you port your code one day.